# How do you document Reverse Engineering

Tags: documentation

Currently I am working on a project in high school where I am talking about reverse engineering malware. I am currently all set on every topic except how reverse engineering is documented in a business setting.

Hopefully someone can give me some insight!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to document a reverse engineering operation?](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/15947/how-to-document-a-reverse-engineering-operation)

Answer (score 1):

I work with Onenote. The options to devide into sections, add screen shots are quite useful.

I open a section for each project, a page for each topic. There is often an Ideas page, resources page and various pages for research tasks.